# One to many join with three tables

Tags: mysql, join

I have a tables: sites, campaigns, and `out` for a campaign tracking system I am building. When a link is clicked the out table gets its hits updated where the site id and campaign id match.

In the out table there is a campaign_id and a site_id which both correspond to the sites and campaigns tables respectivly. To complicate things more, each site can has 4 campaigns (campaign_a, campaign_b, campaign_id_reviews, campaign_id_reviews_phone). I want to JOIN the three tables and for each site I want the folllowing to be on one line:

```
site.site_name, site.campaign_id_a, campaigns.campaign_name, out.hits, 
site.campaign_id_b, campaigns.campaign_name, out.hits, 
site.campaign_id_reviews, campaigns.campaign_name, out.hits, 
site.campaign_id_reviews_phone, campaigns.campaign_name, out.hits
```

Here is my attempt which does not bring all the site_id/campaign_id combinations back, it only brings back one record for each site_id and not all site_id/campaign_id combinations

```
SELECT s.*, c.*, o.* FROM sites s
INNER JOIN campaigns c ON s.campaign_id_a=c.campaign_id
INNER JOIN campaigns ON s.campaign_id_b=campaigns.campaign_id
INNER JOIN `out` o ON s.campaign_id_a=o.campaign_id AND s.site_id=o.site_id
WHERE s.site_id NOT IN(100,101)
ORDER BY o.site_id ASC
```

My Create table with 3 record dump:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `sites` (
  `site_id` mediumint(4) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `site_name` varchar(70) NOT NULL,
  `campaign_id_a` tinyint(4) NOT NULL,
  `campaign_id_b` tinyint(4) NOT NULL,
  `a_display_name` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `b_display_name` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `campaign_id_reviews` tinyint(4) NOT NULL,
  `campaign_id_reviews_phone` tinyint(3) NOT NULL DEFAULT '4',
  PRIMARY KEY (`site_id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `site_id` (`site_id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `site_name` (`site_name`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=102 ;

INSERT INTO `sites` (`site_id`, `site_name`, `campaign_id_a`, `campaign_id_b`, `a_display_name`, `b_display_name`, `campaign_id_reviews`, `campaign_id_reviews_phone`) VALUES
(1, 'example.com', 1, 8, 'hard456', 'easy123', 3, 4),
(2, 'example.org', 1, 8, 'hard456', 'easy123', 3, 4),
(3, 'example.net', 8, 8, 'easy123', 'easy123', 3, 4);



CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `out` (
  `out_id` mediumint(7) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `site_id` tinyint(4) NOT NULL,
  `campaign_id` tinyint(4) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `hits` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `date_last_hit` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  PRIMARY KEY (`out_id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `site2campaign` (`site_id`,`campaign_id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=101 ;

INSERT INTO `out` (`out_id`, `site_id`, `campaign_id`, `hits`, `date_last_hit`) VALUES
(19, 60, 3, 418, '2015-11-16 22:52:33'),
(10, 2, 1, 1135, '2015-11-15 04:51:32'),
(20, 60, 1, 1710, '2015-11-14 13:52:20');




CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `campaigns` (
  `campaign_id` tinyint(4) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `campaign_name` varchar(60) NOT NULL,
  `network` varchar(60) NOT NULL,
  `url` varchar(400) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`campaign_id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=10 ;

INSERT INTO `campaigns` (`campaign_id`, `campaign_name`, `network`, `url`) VALUES
(1, 'Hard456', 'Hard Network', 'exampleURL'),
(3, 'medium678', 'Medium Network', 'examplewithURL'),
(8, 'easy123', 'Easy Network', 'exampleURLLoaction');
(4, 'none23', 'None Network', 'urlExample');
```

Comment: You could try using temporary tables. Would make your queries look much simpler.

Comment: I think temp tables would complicate things on a high traffic DB, high cost just to make it look simple. I don't see how I could use temp tables to bring back all the data I needed

Comment: Not necessary for production ofcourse. I only wanted to understand your use case better.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is you are overwriting columns names. Although I have not tested it this should work. You can work on a similar pattern to get the out.hits for each campaign id.

```
SELECT
    r3.*, c4.campaign_name c_name_rev_phone
FROM
    (SELECT
            r2.*, c3.campaign_name c_name_rev
    FROM
        (SELECT 
            r1.*, c2.campaign_name c_name_b
        FROM
            (SELECT 
                s1.site_id s_id, 
                s1.site_name sname, 
                s1.campaign_id_a c_id_a, 
                s1.campaign_id_b c_id_b,
                s1.campaign_id_reviews c_id_rev,
                s1.campaign_id_reviews_phone c_id_rev_phone,
                c1.campaign_name c_name_a 
            FROM sites s1 JOIN campaigns c1 ON s1.campaign_id_a = c1.campaign_id ) r1
        JOIN campaigns c2 ON c2.campaign_id=r1.c_id_b ) r2
    JOIN campaigns c3 ON c3.campaign_id=r2.c_id_rev ) r3
JOIN campaigns c4 on c4.campaign_id=r3.c_id_rev_phone;
```

**Edit 1-**

As per the sample data provided in the question the result of the following query would be

```
SELECT s.*, c.* FROM sites s
INNER JOIN campaigns c ON s.campaign_id_a=c.campaign_id
INNER JOIN campaigns ON s.campaign_id_b=campaigns.campaign_id
WHERE s.site_id NOT IN(100,101);
```

Result:

```
site_id |site_name      |campaign_id_a  |campaign_id_b  |a_display_name |b_display_name |campaign_id_reviews    |campaign_id_reviews_phone  |campaign_id    |campaign_name  |network        |url
--------|---------------|---------------|---------------|---------------|---------------|-----------------------|---------------------------|---------------|---------------|---------------|------------------
1       |example.com    |1              |8              |hard456        |easy123        |3                      |4                          |1              |Hard456        |Hard Network   |exampleURL
2       |example.org    |1              |8              |hard456        |easy123        |3                      |4                          |1              |Hard456        |Hard Network   |exampleURL
3       |example.net    |8              |8              |easy123        |easy123        |3                      |4                          |8              |easy123        |Easy Network   |exampleURLLoaction
```

Result of query in answer:

```
s_id    |sname          |c_id_a |c_id_b |c_id_rev   |c_id_rev_phone |c_name_a   |c_name_b   |c_name_rev |c_name_rev_phone
------------------------|-------|-------|-----------|---------------|-----------|-----------|-----------|----------------
1       |example.com    |1      |8      |3          |4              |Hard456    |easy123    |medium678  |none23
2       |example.org    |1      |8      |3          |4              |Hard456    |easy123    |medium678  |none23
3       |example.net    |8      |8      |3          |4              |easy123    |easy123    |medium678  |none23
```

Notice how campaign names for `campaign_id_a`, `campaign_id_b`, `campaign_id_reviews` etc are individually fetched.

Here is the query that would give you the complete answer:

```
SELECT
r3.*, 
c4.campaign_name c_name_rev_phone,
o4.hits hits_rev_phone
FROM
    (SELECT
            r2.*, 
            c3.campaign_name c_name_rev,
            o3.hits hits_rev
    FROM
        (SELECT 
            r1.*, 
            c2.campaign_name c_name_b, 
            o2.hits hits_b
        FROM
            (SELECT 
                s1.site_id s_id, 
                s1.site_name sname, 
                s1.campaign_id_a c_id_a, 
                s1.campaign_id_b c_id_b,
                s1.campaign_id_reviews c_id_rev,
                s1.campaign_id_reviews_phone c_id_rev_phone,
                c1.campaign_name c_name_a,
                o1.hits hits_a
            FROM sites s1 JOIN campaigns c1 ON s1.campaign_id_a = c1.campaign_id JOIN `out` o1 ON (c1.campaign_id=o1.campaign_id AND o1.site_id=s1.site_id)) r1
        JOIN campaigns c2 ON c2.campaign_id=r1.c_id_b JOIN `out` o2 ON (c2.campaign_id=o2.campaign_id AND o2.site_id=r1.s_id)) r2
    JOIN campaigns c3 ON c3.campaign_id=r2.c_id_rev JOIN `out` o3 ON (c3.campaign_id=o3.campaign_id AND o3.site_id=r2.s_id)) r3
JOIN campaigns c4 on c4.campaign_id=r3.c_id_rev_phone JOIN `out` o4 ON (c4.campaign_id=o4.campaign_id AND o4.site_id=r3.s_id);
```

This would give an empty result for the sample data set your have provided because a lot of `campaign_id`, `site_id` combinations are not present in table `out`. Since we are doing an `INNER` join you would lose out on this information. If you want `hits` to be reported as `0` when `site_id`, `campaign_id` combination is not present then you need to use a `LEFT JOIN`.

Feel free to revert if this is not what you want.

Comment: I think this concept is on the right track but the query you created returns the same results as the query above in my question without the "INNER JOIN `out` o ON s.campaign_id_a=o.campaign_id AND s.site_id=o.site_id". My main problem is getting back the hits in the out table for each campaign_id in the sites table. I have tried countless times trying to add in the out table but can not seem to figure it out.

Comment: This does not return the same result. In your case if you remove the join to `out` the output would return just one campaign_name that for campaign_id_a from the site table. If you understand this then you can easily extend it to out.hits. This is because column campaign_name's value is picked up from its first reference which came when you did the first inner join. I will update the answer to include out.hits as well but it is important for you to understand what is wrong with the query in the question.

Answer (score 0):

You appear to join against campaigns twice, but only ever return anything that matches on compaign_id_a. Campaign_id_b is ignored in the results while the other 2 campaign ids are not processed at all.

Splitting it up to get each campaign id and union the results together:-

```
(SELECT s.site_id,
        s.site_name,
        s.campaign_id_a,
        s.campaign_id_b,
        s.a_display_name,
        s.b_display_name,
        s.campaign_id_reviews,
        s.campaign_id_reviews_phone,
        o.out_id,
        o.hits,
        o.date_last_hit, 
        c.campaign_id,
        c.campaign_name,
        c.network,
        c.url 
FROM sites s
INNER JOIN campaigns c ON s.campaign_id_a = c.campaign_id
INNER JOIN `out` o ON c.campaign_id = o.campaign_id AND s.site_id = o.site_id
WHERE s.site_id NOT IN (100,101))
UNION
(SELECT s.site_id,
        s.site_name,
        s.campaign_id_a,
        s.campaign_id_b,
        s.a_display_name,
        s.b_display_name,
        s.campaign_id_reviews,
        s.campaign_id_reviews_phone,
        o.out_id,
        o.hits,
        o.date_last_hit, 
        c.campaign_id,
        c.campaign_name,
        c.network,
        c.url 
FROM sites s
INNER JOIN campaigns c ON s.campaign_id_b = c.campaign_id
INNER JOIN `out` o ON c.campaign_id = o.campaign_id AND s.site_id = o.site_id
WHERE s.site_id NOT IN (100,101))
UNION
(SELECT s.site_id,
        s.site_name,
        s.campaign_id_a,
        s.campaign_id_b,
        s.a_display_name,
        s.b_display_name,
        s.campaign_id_reviews,
        s.campaign_id_reviews_phone,
        o.out_id,
        o.hits,
        o.date_last_hit, 
        c.campaign_id,
        c.campaign_name,
        c.network,
        c.url 
FROM sites s
INNER JOIN campaigns c ON s.campaign_id_reviews = c.campaign_id
INNER JOIN `out` o ON c.campaign_id = o.campaign_id AND s.site_id = o.site_id
WHERE s.site_id NOT IN (100,101))
UNION
(SELECT s.site_id,
        s.site_name,
        s.campaign_id_a,
        s.campaign_id_b,
        s.a_display_name,
        s.b_display_name,
        s.campaign_id_reviews,
        s.campaign_id_reviews_phone,
        o.out_id,
        o.hits,
        o.date_last_hit, 
        c.campaign_id,
        c.campaign_name,
        c.network,
        c.url 
FROM sites s
INNER JOIN campaigns c ON s.campaign_id_reviews_phone = c.campaign_id
INNER JOIN `out` o ON c.campaign_id = o.campaign_id AND s.site_id = o.site_id
WHERE s.site_id NOT IN (100,101))
ORDER BY site_id ASC
```

Comment: As much as I want this to work, I keep getting errors on the Order by so I took it out. Then I kept getting errors with the inner join "on c.campaign_id_a". I a also not completley understanding how these unions are working

Comment: Fixed a couple of typos and it should now work. Also listed the columns specifically in the SELECT statements to avoid duplicate column names.